# Can I open a folder in the current Finder window, rather than getting a new window for each folder?

Tags: macos, file-management, finder

In Mac's Finder, I have a million windows piled on top of each other when I finally find a file I want.

Is there any way to select a subfolder and when it opens, have it REPLACE the current open window in order to avoid pileup?

Answer (score 10):

Did you unselect the option *"Always open folders in a new window"*?

[image: folder]

Or, you could use the ***Columns view***:

[image: columns]

Comment: Also, if you still want the old behaviour (open a new window), double click while holding down Command (just figured this out...)

Answer (score 1):

Opening one (and *only* one) window for each folder is called a "[spatial file manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_file_manager)", and was common up to OS 9. In OS X, it's still used when your Finder does not show the sidebar and toolbar. Showing those is toggled by the little [show/hide toolbar button](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2470) in the top-right corner.

So: ensure the toolbar is shown.

Or, if you like it hidden: hold down Option while double-clicking (or while pressing Command-O or Comand-Down) to open a new folder. That will still open or activate the spatial window for the new folder (which will even have remembered its previous position) but will also close the window of the parent folder right away.

(Of course, when your Finder actually shows the toolbar, then Studer's [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/116244/mac-select-a-folder-and-it-replaces-current-open-window/116247#116247) may apply to your situation as well.)