# How can I make Finder always show the Side Bar when mounting a volume?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, finder

In OS X 10.6, Finder usually looks something like this:

[image]

The Finder window looks like that when you double-click on most folders or drives. However, whenever I mount a Truecrypt Volume and double-click that, it looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way to default to the first view option for all types of folders? I tried view options in Finder, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Knowing the name might help find a solution: clicking the toolbar control button toggles the so-called [spatial file manager](http://superuser.com/questions/116244/can-i-open-a-folder-in-the-current-finder-window-rather-than-getting-a-new-windo/116264#116264), aka spatial Finder.

Comment: Does `defaults read com.apple.desktopservices` give you any output? (Maybe you've set `DSDontWriteNetworkStores` but I'd not expect that to affect a local volume.)

Comment: @Arjan, the result from Terminal is `Domain com.apple.desktopservices does not exist`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your truecrypt volume is not formatted as JHFS+ (and it won't be).  I usually format my tc volumes at fat 32.  The easiest work around is to select the truecrypt icon from the left hand side of a finder window that is already open.

Even if you get preferences set for the session that the volume is mounted you will start with the simple finder style folder the next time you mount the volume and double click on it from the desktop.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're suggesting here? I have a FAT-32 partition (filesharing with Linux) that's auto-mounted when I open OSX, and that doesn't show up in 'Spatial Finder Mode'

Comment: ... but I DO have an JHFS+ formatted volume that doesn't show in 'Spatial Finder Mode.' Interesting

Comment: I know that fat32 is supported in JHFS+ but I don't know how truecrypt is managing this.  For example, look at the terminal and do ls -l /Volumes.  You will see your volume.  Then do df -h and you will see a different path.  Mine looks like:

/private/var/folders/4U/4UPMrNiWE8CasZbClZe49k+++TQ/-Tmp-/.truecrypt_aux_mnt1

In that folder is a binary control file and a volume.dmg file ... hmmm

Comment: Closest answer; it definitely has something to do with the formatting

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if you can set this to default, but to make it look like the first, click the small, pill-shaped button in the top right corner.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes - Mr. Man is correct.  Click that pill-shape button and it will show the normal finder view

Comment: @Mr. Man, this works - thanks! However, when the folder is closed and reopened, it's back 'like in the lower picture' again. Any way to set the default view option?

Answer (score 4):

Based on "[Explaining the Finder's view options and toolbar visibility](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20030305025744788)", you're expecting the right behavior and the state of the window should be saved in .DS_Store -- at least as the Finder worked in 2003.

My guess is that [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org) is getting in the way here -- maybe for a good reason.

The above article says that the .DS_Store file "is written when the volume containing the directory is ejected". It's possible Finder tries to write the volume after TrueCrypt has closed the encryption channel. If this is the case, then the fix would be for the TrueCrypt developers to fix this (or, if you have the OS X development skills, do it yourself and contribute the change back to the community).

(Update to the latest TrueCrypt version if you've aren't already there.)

Another possibility is that TrueCrypt is deliberately not allowing this change to save to enhance its plausible deniability. Finder may be writing something about this volume to its preferences. If TrueCrypt were to allow this to happen normally, then this trace information wouldn't allow TrueCrypt users to plausibly deny that they haven't used encryption software.

Comment: So far yours sounds like the most plausible answer: "This currently cannot be done" ;-)

Comment: Yes, that would be the short interpretation of my long winded answer. Sorry it couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: @trolle3000, but given your comment at Hasaan's anwer: you did have some .DS_Store file, right? After you deleted that, did it come back? And if you delete it again, does it come back when you just move the Finder window?

Comment: @Arjan, the `.DS_Store` files did not re-appear

Answer (score 2):

Delete the hidden .DS_Store file in that folder

Comment: This didn't work.

Comment: Onyx has an option to delete all .DS_store files to reset view settings.

Answer (score 1):

Try plugging in the drive then go to Finder preferences at

```
~/Library/Preferences/
```

then open the com.apple.finder.plist file. 
Search down this for a configuration drop down list for the drive. Click "WindowState" and there should be a tick box for "ShowSideBar" tick this and it should work hopefully

Comment: Hi. I can't find any drive-specific drop down lists. I tried to tick all `ShowSideBar`'s I could find, but it didn't work.

Comment: Worked for me _after_ I restarted Finder.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just like Mr. Man said, the button in the top right corner of the finder will expand your finder to the *normal* view.  If you want to to set defaults for a certain view, *right click /cmd click* anywhere inside the finder window and you should see an option - *view options or cmd +J*, both work.

**update**:  Actually - try expanding your finder to show the default layout, as mentioned above, then close and re-open....if im correct, it should re-open  in standard view.( could be wrong, @ work on a linux machine, so i cannot replicate it.)

[image]

Comment: However, there is no option to do what trolle3000 wants, so it can't be set as a default.

Comment: The close and re-open didn't work - it goes back to icon view.